# Is it possible to use any QML Parser Tool?

Tags: qt, parsing, qml

Is it possible to use any QML Parser Tool  in order to see how we should parse our Qml Application which has also use C++ libraries thanks to qmlRegisterType ???

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve? Qt can already parse the QML (and Qt is open-source, if you are curious about how it is done), so what's your purpose?

Comment: I have a qml project which contains multiple applications such as media, radio... I would like to compose them and it becomes separated projects not one project. Therefore i would like to use qml parser tool like xml parser tool, cpp parser tool which tells how i should seperate them and their dependencies

Comment: How can Qt parse QML, which way could you give more explanations ?

Comment: Can you give an example of how a cpp parser tool helps you to split?

Comment: cpp parser tool could apply an cpp project and it shows the class, struct, library dependencies for availability and efficiency. Like that, i would like to use a qml parser tool to see media app dependencies and radio app dependencies separately. So, i could see how to i divide my project two different part as app

Comment: @ymoreau i found  /Qt/5.8/Src/qtdeclarative/src/qml/parser . how can i use it

Comment: What you want is apparently a tool to analyse your code and project, please edit your question and explain more clearly your need. What do you want to achieve with such a tool, and maybe similar tools you know for other languages. I don't know any myself, clarify your question and maybe someone will bring an answer.